# Check whether Pip-Install Module Installed Properly

Tags: python, pip

How do I check whether the "pip-install" module is properly installed? I think I installed it a while ago
but when I entered in pip `install scikit-learn` I got the "invalid syntax" message. I am working with Python 2.7,
Vista 32-bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest smoketest is: start python commandline, import the package.

Comment: I've been using this trick for years: `python -c "import MYMODULE" 2>&-|| pip install MYMODULE`

Comment: @Hugo Tavares Can you say what it does, in words?

Comment: `python -c` runs any python command. It can fail or not. The `2>&-` means "send stderr of that command to nowhere, not even /dev/null". If that python command (`import MYMODULE`) fails, it is going to run `pip install MYMODULE`. If it does not fail, it does not run `pip install MYMODULE`. It is a shell short circuit trick. Take this as an example: `$ python -c "import MYMODULE" 2>&- && echo "import succeeded" || echo "import failed"`.

Comment: Does that answer your question, @user1374969?

Comment: @HugoTavares Yes, thank you very much. Dombey, I'd make sure that you have set the BLAS environment variable that scikit-learn requires.